Title of Work about "Barber? who tries to make everyone like him buts ends up destitute"
My friend told me once that there was a literary work (book, play?, etc.) about a barber who tries to make everyone like him but ends up destitute because of that singular focus.  It may have been shakespeare but I can't google that topic.  Anyone have any ideas?

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Identification requests are on topic here, but we appreciate more details, as described in our guidelines for identification requests. (And it was definitely not Shakespeare.)

If you are thinking Shakespeare, the closest match would be Timon of Athens.

The Life of Tymon of Athens, often shortened to Timon of Athens, is a play written by William Shakespeare and likely also Thomas Middleton in about 1606. It was published in the First Folio in 1623. Timon lavishes his wealth on parasitic companions until he is poor and rejected by them. He then denounces all of mankind, and isolates himself in a cave in the wilderness.

That said, Timon was not a barber, nor a Berber.

It also doesn't match the motivation: Timon doesn't give money to please people, people please Timon to get money. Timon, of course, was a real person, too.

Ah, I never actually got around to doing the show, so I was operating off of the cliff notes and my memories of the show being about "a guy who spends money on all of his friends only to find that they're ungrateful bastards". Still, I feel it's a close enough to match, especially if they are right that they were thinking Shakespeare.

Oh, I think you're right, and already voted accordingly! I was just additionally pointing out that OPs friend's details aren't quite right, that they sound like they misremembered certain things.
